# issue with Javascript image changer

Tags: javascript

I have a script running on my page to change the images. I want to repeat it 6 times to use in other places on the same page, but it wont work when I repeat it.

```
  var delay = 2000 //set delay in miliseconds
  var curindex = 0

  var randomimages = new Array()

  randomimages[0] = "hhh200.jpg"
  randomimages[1] = "ray200.jpg"

  var preload = new Array()

   for (n = 0; n < randomimages.length; n++) {
      preload[n] = new Image()
      preload[n].src = randomimages[n]
  }

  document.write('<img name="defaultimage" src="' + randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random() * (randomimages.length))] + '">')

   function rotateimage() {

      if (curindex == (tempindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (randomimages.length)))) {
          curindex = curindex == 0 ? 1 : curindex - 1
      } else curindex = tempindex

      document.images.defaultimage.src = randomimages[curindex]
  }

  setInterval("rotateimage()", delay)
```

Can anyone see why it's not working?

Comment: Need more details than "but it wont work" in order to help.

Comment: you code is working on my FF 7.0.1

Comment: yes i know it works but when i copy and paste it somewhere else on the page none of the images will change ? they all stay stationery

Comment: copy pasting as is multiple times on the same page may not work because the same variables, arrays are being used and clobbering each other

Answer (score 0):

If you are just copying and pasting it somewhere else in the page as is, then you are overriding your variable values, and you are giving both images the same name, so those are 2 problems right there. You should put it all inside on function and call that function in the 2 places you want.

Try this.

```
function randomImage(randomImages, imageName) {
    var delay = 2000 //set delay in miliseconds
    var curindex = 0  

    var preload = new Array()

    for (n = 0; n < randomImages.length; n++) {
        preload[n] = new Image()
        preload[n].src = randomImages[n]
    }

    document.write('<img name="' + imageName + '" src="' + randomImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * (randomImages.length))] + '">');

    function rotateimage() {
       var tempindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (randomImages.length));
       if (curindex == tempindex) {
           curindex = curindex == 0 ? 1 : curindex - 1
       } else curindex = tempindex

       document.images[imageName].src = randomImages[curindex];
    }

    setInterval("rotateimage()", delay);
}



// and then to use it, create your image arrays outside of the function, and call the function.

var images1 = new Array();
images1[0] = "hhh200.jpg";
images1[1] = "ray200.jpg";

var images2 = new Array();
images2[0] = "hhh200.jpg";
images2[1] = "ray200.jpg";


randomImage(images1, 'imageOneName');



randomImage(images2, 'imageTwoName');
```

I have not tested this code, but this is the general idea you should follow.